# AngularJS templates title not rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the following code to display page titles for each of my AngularJS app template, but whenever I try to enter an invalid URL to test the .otherwise I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at http://localhost/app/js/app.js:34:43
```

Below is the app.js, index.html code used:

app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize']);
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

       $routeProvider.when('/home', 
                {     templateUrl: 'templates/index.html', 
                      controller: 'MainController',
                      title: 'Welcome to Home Page'
                });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({
                                    redirectTo: '/home',
                                   title: '404 Not found'

                                 });

}]);


myApp.run(['$location', '$rootScope', function($location, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
        $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
    });
}]);
```

Index.html:

```
<title ng-bind="title +' - MyAPP Home'"> - MyApp</title>
```

Can someone please help by telling me what exactly I am doing wrong and how to fix?

Thanks

Comment: @Ben no it is correct like this

Comment: is your ng-app declared above your title?

Comment: @Wawy just replied to you there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
myApp.run(['$location', '$rootScope', function($location, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
        $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
    });
}]);
```

to this and it will work

```
myApp.run(['$location', '$rootScope', function($location, $rootScope) {
     $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, currentRoute, previousRoute) {
        $rootScope.title = currentRoute.title;
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try

```
 $routeProvider.otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/home',
      title: ''

 });
```

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work :( and that what frustrate me more as it should work!

Answer (score 1):

I am looking at the documentation right now and I don't see any field called title that can be used in that way, could you have a read at:

[angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider)

I'll make myself more clear then, you shouldn't be adding random properties in the route object just because you can. You are getting this error message because every time a route changes the event is fired, in this case, when you change the url to something that doesn't match /home, the default route kicks in, which then looks for that random property you set on the route object which it won't find, since you haven't defined it for any other case than the route /home.

Also, any property that you have to access with $$ means is private to angular and it shouldn't be used lightly (what if in the next release they add a private property called title and you are overwriting it?)

If you want to set the title of the page when you have change the route, then you should do that in the controller that gets assigned to that route.

Comment: title is defined in code, please read my code in question or @BKM reply

Comment: Your theory is correct but not with templates as with templates i have index.html with ng-view section and index.html is the only file having the title tag then all other template files don't have title tag, else what's the use of templates, and I need to have a title that will change from page to page...so this approach is not good. If you have any thoughts of dynamic titles with templates please let me know, thanks

Comment: You can still access $rootScope from 'MainController' and set the title there.

Comment: No need for all of this, I've got the answer already, thanks though for your effort and time :)

Comment: I'm glad you found your answer, just trying to help here to achieve the best solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

The title property in the provider is required by the routeChange Event.

You should try something like this in order to fix.

```
  $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/index.html',
        controller: 'MainController',
        title: 'Welcome to my page'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home',
        title: ''
     });
```

Comment: please check code in question, I've already tried this before

Comment: sorry, I was testing the controller to prepare my answer.